# MySQL find records by regexp

Tags: regex, regexp-like

I have some telegram bot database with a lot of spammers accounts.
These usernames looks like:

> KistlerLakisha4577
>   EnnalsQuentin974
>   GolobDemetrius1444

So it looks like CamelCase word with 2 capital letters (first and some middle) and with numbers at the end of the string - **CamelCase777**.
I'm using the next pattern to find it my DB, but it's not working correctly:

```
(^[A-Z]|[a-z])[0-9]*
```

What is the better way to find **ExampleRecord777** with regexp?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
[A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z][a-z]+[0-9]+
```

Check [**demo and explaination**](https://regex101.com/r/UMe9RG/1)

```
[A-Z]  -- First capital letter
[a-z]+ -- At least one lowercase letter
[A-Z]  -- Another uppercase letter
[a-z]+ -- Again at least one lowercase letter
[0-9]+ -- At least one number
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but seems like that don't work for REGEXP MySQL construction, the query returned me wrong data :(